# Panda Dataframe - generate Unique ID based on condition and append consistent

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique-id

I am trying to create a new column which assigns unique IDs based on certain conditions. e.g. 'name' columns Using the below:

`dt['id'] = dt.groupby(dt.name.tolist(), sort=False).ngroup() + 1`

Example of data:

```
Name    Date
John    01-01-2020
Jane    02-01-2020
John    03-01-2020
Smith   03-01-2020
```

To

```
Name    Date         UID
John    01-01-2020   33
Jane    02-01-2020   34
John    03-01-2020   33
Smith   03-01-2020   35
```

And when ran again, the IDs change:

```
Name    Date         UID
John    01-01-2020   54
Jane    02-01-2020   55
John    03-01-2020   54
Smith   03-01-2020   56
```

This works, however, is does not generate consistent data when the dataframe is rerun or more data is appended to the dataframe. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This works fine for me every time... it's consistent and if I add more data it works as expected. Can you explain more about why this doesn't work?

Comment: When I rerun the dataframe, the UID changes and gets assigned to a different record. E.g. if UID for record is 345, and run it again, it changes to 378.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the undesirable behavior?

Comment: I hope the changes above provide more clarity. Thanks

Comment: @Sama I am not what your issue is. As cosmic_inquiry says, it works for me and every time is giving the same result.